# ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] socket not letting me connect to my pc

Tags: python, sockets

I'm sorry for repeating this question but I couldn't seem to find an answer I could understand.
I am running python 3.9.1 on windows 10.
I'm getting this error message:

> my_socket.connect(("127.0.0.1", 8820))
> ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

I am a python beginner following a book that said this code should run perfectly but doesn't for me anyone know why this is(I have tried different ports and none seem to work)?

```
import socket

my_socket = socket.socket()
my_socket.connect(('127.0.0.1', 8820))
my_socket.send('Hello world!'.encode())
data = my_socket.recv(1024).decode()
print('the server send:' + data)
my_socket.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I was missing the server code.